# Добавить столбец со значениями из другого DataFrame. Связь по совпадающим значениям 'id'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

```
id              winner
2   mIICvQHh    white
3   kWKvrqYL    white
4   9tXo1AUZ    white
10  HgKLWPsz    white
14  u7i6dOaJ    white
17  EwaK0IsE    black
25  ifUMWtVj    white
```

У нас есть такой дата-сет с лэйблами(выше-часть)

И такой дата-сет(тоже часть)

```
0       ifUMWtVj
1       5kY5WUxA
2       hQLKJ68q
3       JMejEQFl
4       04B0N7Xa
5       AmudwqU7
6       HhMYxLAh
7       QsXoSaql
8       3RT1kKyr
9       TdvWu2Vv
10      kY9tnUF3
11      IFXc12eJ
12      3gQoIkwB
13      u7i6dOaJ
14      MKlLaYyA
```

Как мы можем по совпадающим id перенести лэйблы из первого во второй?

P.S все id первого дата-сета совпадают со всеми id второго

Comment: @MaxU Поправил вопрос

Comment: и что вы хотит получить на выходе?

Comment: Добавить лэйблы ко второму дата-сету, имея первый дата-сет, в котором есть совпадающие id с первым и который уже имеет лэйблы('winner')

Comment: Они разбросаны, сейчас попробую вывести, где совпадают

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).

Исходные DataFrame's:

```
In [13]: d1
Out[13]:
          id winner
2   mIICvQHh  white
3   kWKvrqYL  white
4   9tXo1AUZ  white
10  HgKLWPsz  white
14  u7i6dOaJ  white
17  EwaK0IsE  black
25  ifUMWtVj  white

In [14]: d2
Out[14]:
          id
0   ifUMWtVj
1   5kY5WUxA
2   hQLKJ68q
3   JMejEQFl
4   04B0N7Xa
5   AmudwqU7
6   HhMYxLAh
7   QsXoSaql
8   3RT1kKyr
9   TdvWu2Vv
10  kY9tnUF3
11  IFXc12eJ
12  3gQoIkwB
13  u7i6dOaJ
14  MKlLaYyA
```

Решение:

```
In [15]: res = d2.merge(d1, on='id', how='left')
```

Результат:

```
In [16]: res
Out[16]:
          id winner
0   ifUMWtVj  white
1   5kY5WUxA    NaN
2   hQLKJ68q    NaN
3   JMejEQFl    NaN
4   04B0N7Xa    NaN
5   AmudwqU7    NaN
6   HhMYxLAh    NaN
7   QsXoSaql    NaN
8   3RT1kKyr    NaN
9   TdvWu2Vv    NaN
10  kY9tnUF3    NaN
11  IFXc12eJ    NaN
12  3gQoIkwB    NaN
13  u7i6dOaJ  white
14  MKlLaYyA    NaN
```

Comment: Да, это то, что нужно.Большое спасибо!

Comment: Возник такой момент.У меня почему-то на выходе shape немного больше чем на входе

Comment: @overfitt, можете привести __воспроизводимый__ пример?

Comment: shape у обоих дата-сетов большой,не залить.Попробую сам решить проблему